# Conditional operations for rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to have a condition that says if value in 'prediction' < 0 then 'return' = 0.

Here's my dataframe

```
    returns prediction
0   -1.005705   0.999999
1   0.005952    1.000000
2   0.000000    -0.999891
3   0.020000    -1.000000
4   0.000000    1.000000
5   0.005000    1.000000
6   0.000000    -0.999984
7   -0.005813   -0.999871
```

I tried:

```
df.returns[if df.pred < 0 : df.returns = 0]
```

But i get syntax error

EDIT:

I figured it out on my own `returns[pred < 0] = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.prediction < 0, 'return'] = 0
print df
    returns  prediction  return
0 -1.005705    0.999999     NaN
1  0.005952    1.000000     NaN
2  0.000000   -0.999891       0
3  0.020000   -1.000000       0
4  0.000000    1.000000     NaN
5  0.005000    1.000000     NaN
6  0.000000   -0.999984       0
7 -0.005813   -0.999871       0
```

Or if you need overwritten column `returns`:

```
df.loc[df.prediction < 0, 'returns'] = 0
print df
    returns  prediction
0 -1.005705    0.999999
1  0.005952    1.000000
2  0.000000   -0.999891
3  0.000000   -1.000000
4  0.000000    1.000000
5  0.005000    1.000000
6  0.000000   -0.999984
7  0.000000   -0.999871
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, I was actually able to figure it before you posted this. Thanks though your way is interesting